# Build multiple binaries with different startup forms in one step in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

My project has two GUI forms. One is the "internal" form and the other is the "public" form. This is not related to information hiding or security, just presentation.

What I am doing now is:

1. Right click "Project" select "Properties"
2. Change "Startup object" to "Public_Form"
3. Click "Build"
4. In Explorer, copy `bin\Release` to `bin\Release-public` and run my post build scripts
5. Change "Startup object" to "Internal_Form"
6. Click "Build"
7. In Explorer, copy `bin\Release` to `bin\Release-internal` and run my post build scripts

I keep goofing it up and swapping internal with public.

In other words, I need two separate binaries that are built in one single step, with two separate post-build scripts. "Be more careful" is not an acceptable answer to this question.

Can I accomplish my build task with one click rather than a couple of dozen?

Comment: Why not have one binary and have it decide which form to show upon launching?

Comment: Specifications outside my control. Besides, I don't think this should be a terribly difficult problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Create another project in your solution alongside your original project.

In the new project, delete the default form that VS adds and delete the App.config.

Add the same references to this project as you did the original project.

Right click on your new project, and click "Add Existing....". **Add as Links** all your forms and other code files from your original project. Make sure you Add them as Links.  You add them as links by changing the dropdown selection at the bottom of the Add Existing window:

[image]

The only file that you do not add is your Public_Form. Instead move your Internal_Form over to this project. Make sure in your second project you setup the startup form to the Internal_Form.

Now, when you build, you will have two different bin folders.  Since you added all the files in the second project as Links, you have not duplicated the files: you've just made it so that two different projects share the same exact source files (except that one form).
In Solution Explorer it will look something like this:

[image]

Notice that in `InternalProject`, the files that are shared with AlphaProject have a special little arrow icon on them to indicate that they are linked.  That means that any changes you make to those files will be reflected in both projects.